# Does anyone recognized this PEX Crimp System (Make/Model)?

Tags: plumbing, tools, pex

Does anyone recognized this product?
Looks like a good idea.

There is this red spacer ring to help position and hold the crimp ring in the right place.

I want to know more about it.

[image: Picture of PEX pipe with crimp ring and red spacer]

Comment: Sold in a shop in your area?

Comment: Is there something special about it?

Answer (score 1):

This is just one variation of the PEX crimp ring.  Some rings come with plastic to hold them in place, some do not.  If you do a search for "3copper pro crimp ring" you will find this.  You can buy these at the big-box hardware stores, online, and probably at the smaller hardware stores as well.